# how to develop complete software suite/platform?

Tags: java, enterprise

here's an example of a company selling complete software suite/platform

www.ql2.com/technology/platform.php

i wonder how are such suite/platforms developped ? do you have to use J2EE ?

i am more interested in how this company is able to produce their own proprietary WebQL language.

www.automationanywhere.com/products/AAServer.htm

is another similar company selling "servers"....how are such proprietary servers developped with Java technology ?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're using Java, it all starts at public static void main(String args[]). Fill in what you want it to. And no, no one says you have to use J2EE, or Java.
2. They understand how to write languages and interpreters/runtimes for those languages. There are several good beginngers books on creating your own domain specific or general purpose language. I recommend also reading up on ANTLR.
3. See #1. There isn't any magic involved, just practice.